# Convert select into stored procedure best approach

Tags: sql, firebird

I use this SQL to get count for every group of type.

```
select 
    mytype, count(mytype)
from types1
group by 1
```

The result is 5 records with count for each type. I need to convert this to a stored procedure; should I write the above SQL using `For...Select` or should I return single value using `Select...Where...Into` 5 times for each type?

I will use the return counts to update a master table and types may increase in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you want out of the procedure:

- If you want the same output as your select with five rows, use a `FOR SELECT`. You will get one row for each type and an associated count. This is probably the "standard" approach.
- If however you want five output variables, one for each count of each type, you can use five queries of the form `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM types1 WHERE mytype = 'type1' INTO :type1`. Realize though that this will be five queries and you may be better off doing a single `FOR SELECT` query and looping through the returned rows in the procedure. Also note that if you at some point add a sixth type you will have to change this procedure to add the additional type.
- If you want to query a single type, you can also do something like the following, which will return a single row with a single count for the type in the input parameter:

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE GetTypeCount(
      TypeName VARCHAR(256)
  )
  RETURNS (
      TypeCount INTEGER
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(1)
      FROM types1
      WHERE mytype = :TypeName
      INTO :TypeCount;

      SUSPEND
  END
  ```

Comment: updated my question.....there is no way other than hard coding each type to get the count ?

Comment: @Welliam Added a third option

Comment: one question please which is more faster calling the procedure 5 times to return type count for each type or doing one for...select for all types ?

Comment: @Welliam I would think one select should be faster since it only hits the database once.